# Bootstrap.yml not being found/read on Spring Boot 2 application deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to deploy an Spring Boot 2 application on a Tomcat server. I've already done the 3 steps that I have found in multiple docs, being those:

- Extend from `SpringBootServletInitializer`
- Mark the embedded servlet container as provided.
- Update packaging to war

The problem I'm having is that it seems the `bootstrap yml` file (which works if I run the application as a standalone) placed on `src/main/resources` is not being used. No matter what I put on the `bootstrap.yml`, the application always tries to get the configuration from http://localhost:8888

> 17:35:54.193 [localhost-startStop-16] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
>
> 17:35:54.292 [localhost-startStop-16] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
>
> 17:35:54.293 [localhost-startStop-16] WARN  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 1

I have read on another thread that I need to have spring-cloud-starter-config dependency on pom but I can assure I have it.

Here is bootstrap.yml I'm using:

```
spring:
    application:
        name : botbrowser
    cloud:
        config:
            uri: http://isblvdivrrd0003:8080     # config-server url
            profile: ukdev                          # environment
            label: master 
            failFast: true
            overrideNone: false
            overrideSystemProperties: true 
            enabled: true
            allowOverride: true
            retry:                                # connection retrials configuration
                initialInterval: 1000             # first timeout
                multiplier: 1.5                   # factor for subsequence trials (1st trial = initialInterval, 2nd trial = 1st trial * multiplier, ...)
                maxAttempts: 6                    # number of trials
                maxInterval: 5000                 # maximal timeout
```

Any ideas about what could be happening?

Edit:

Including build from pom

```
<build>
<finalName>botbrowser</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>revision</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!-- <phase>initialize</phase> -->
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>validate-the-git-infos</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>validateRevision</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                <generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    ${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties
                </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you verified that the `bootstrap.yml` is getting copied into your WAR and can therefore be found at deploy time? Seeing your build script would help.

Comment: yes, it is. It's inside /WEB-INF/classes. I'm editing the original answer to add the <build> part of pom

Comment: I assume the `bootstrap.yml` is not being found/loaded at all, i.e. no properties there are being used. (You could verify by putting junk in the file and redeploying.) You say this all works fine when run with the embedded web container... Could you add some debug and redeploy so we can see what is getting loaded/configured at startup?

Comment: Ok, I have put it to DEBUG and redeployed. Not sure what I have to ckeck for, but I have compared standalone deployment with tomcat deployment. I see that in standalone it looks for and find bootstrap, and before that,  it finds spring.application.name value from 'configurationProperties'. 

In tomcat, it doesn't seem to look for bootstrap, and the only value it gets from 'configurationProperties' is 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class'

Comment: Any chance you could share it? In mine I see: `2019-09-25 15:17:55,987 DEBUG [main] ConfigFileApplicationListener: Loaded config file 'file:/Users/myservice/target/classes/bootstrap.yml' (classpath:/bootstrap.yml)` and a number of +ve matches from `ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration`

Comment: Sure I can't share, but It's huge.... Any way I could share it? By the way, there is no reference to bootstrap.yml in the whole trace. Also no reference to ConfigFileApplicationListener:

Comment: Javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.html explain where it looks for bootstrap files. There's no logging if no file is found in any of those locations, so I assume that's the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199970/discussion-between-eduardo-hermida-and-andrew-regan).

Answer (score 0):

please check if bootstrap.yml is excluded from jar/war from gradle build